# fscanf variable not setting correctly. possibly realloc()

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Output says all array values are "anxiety" when the words of file fileIn are printing correctly and in order. My problem may be in the realloc()?

```
    ReadIn = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

    while(fscanf(fileIn, "%s", ReadIn) != EOF){
        wordlist = (char **)realloc( wordlist, (numwords + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        printf("%s\n",ReadIn);
        wordlist[numwords] = ReadIn;
        numwords++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numwords; i++){
        printf("%d %s\n", i , wordlist[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
journey
into
fear
and
anxiety.
0 anxiety.
1 anxiety.
2 anxiety.
3 anxiety.
4 anxiety.
5 anxiety.
6 anxiety.
7 anxiety.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make each array pointer point to the `ReadIn` buffer, which will contain the last string that was read in.

You want to duplicate each string that's read in:

```
//change: wordlist[numwords] = ReadIn;
wordlist[numwords] = strdup(ReadIn);
```

You should also take care to free each of those strings when you're done with the `wordlist` array.

And if your compiler's runtime library doesn't have the non-standard, but common, `strdup()` function, it's easy to implement (or find a public domain version of).

Comment: Program4.c: In function ‘main’:
Program4.c:49: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’
Program4.c:49: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: It works! Thanks. I just don't like these errors. using pedantic ansi and Wall

Comment: @Jared: `#include <string.h>` should get the correct declaration of `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0):

wordlist[numwords] = ReadIn;

In the above Line you are simply assigning the address of the 'ReadIn' not the string. so the last string read from the file contained in the 'ReadIn' has been printed repeatedly.

so, you need to copy the read string to your array of of strings,

strcpy(wordlist[numwords], ReadIn);